# JBoss ignores @RemoteBinding annotation

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I would like to specify JNDI name for an EJB3 bean using annotation, but JBoss 5.1.0 GA seems to ignore the annotation completely. Bean's annotations are:

```
@Remote(Foobar.class)
@Stateless(name = "Foobar")
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding="ejb/Foobar")
public class FoobarBean implements Foobar {
...
```

I tested deploying also using @RemoteBindings annotation, but the result was same:

```
@RemoteBindings({@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding="ejb/Foobar")})
```

The bean does not get bound to JNDI with the specified name, and the log file doesn't give any clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are your import statements?  [JBoss 4.2.x and up uses org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.*](http://community.jboss.org/message/410210#410210) instead of org.jboss.annotation.ejb.*

Comment: Great answer. After two hours of going through jboss docs, I completely missed the package renaming. Big thank you.